# Should I use TableView only for multiple rows pages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating some kind of a list app and I have two pages where

1. Is for presenting a list of items (this i will use a `TableView` for sure) and
2. For presenting one item of that previous page list, and that page will only present one item each time.

Now, in that 2nd view I want to use that functionality of a `TableView` row where you can swipe to delete the item, or other options I can insert in this gesture.

Should I use `TableView` so it will be easy to get this functionality or should I just use a regular `ViewController`?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a `UITableView` in both of your two views, however, it might not be intuitive for the user to recognize that the "swipe to delete" feature is available if you are using a `UITableView` with only one row. A `UITableView` with only one row could feel like an fairly empty `UIViewController`, which doesn't scream "swipe me, I might be interactive!" So you may benefit by making the "delete" feature more obvious if it is a really important feature (creating a "Delete" button, or adding some type of "tooltip-style" tutorial on first view). If the feature is of secondary importance, then "hiding" it in a "swipe to delete" function that your users may not find is tolerable.

That being said, it's just as easy to build your own "Swipe to Delete" function into a regular `UIView`, using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. So if a swipe feature is important to you, it's easy to achieve the same "swipe to delete" feature in either scenario.

It's important that you design a great user experience, so use which ever approach makes the most sense to facilitate your app's feature set. In this example, you will get similar results using both a `UITableView` or a `UIViewController`. If it were me, I would opt for the `UIViewController` option, since you have more flexibility with the design.

Hope this helps.